# send the form values to multiple pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am working on a web application where I need to send the value from one form to more than one page.

My form is simple :

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="">
    ...
</form>
```

I want the values from the form to be sent to :

- 'page1.php' which will replace the actual page containing the form displaying the message : data saved
- 'page2.php' which will open when I click the submit button to render the data as a PDF file

The problem is that I can only specify only one target using the action attribute of the form.

Anyone can helps ? Thanks in advance.

Could I use JavaScript or jQuery or other ?

Comment: What do you exactly want to do ? When you submit your form, you want more than 1 page to open ?

Comment: did you think about using `$_SESSION` variable to store form data?, the `$_SESSION` will be persistent within all your *.php pages

Comment: Can you clarify your idea @always sunny ?

Comment: @heaner, yes I want the values of the forms sent to two pages the first page is which that contains the form, the second one is not open until I submit the form than a new tab is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using JavaScript and jQuery for example. The easiest way is send two ajax requests:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'page2.php',
        data: $( this ).serialize(),
        success: function() {
             window.open("http://www.stackoverflow.com"); //this page will be open in new tab
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'page1.php',
        data: $( this ).serialize(),
        success: function() {
            window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"; //redirect to this page
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I thought about  doing that but how to open the second page in another tab ?

Comment: @manianis, you could do it using JavaScript too. Just call `window.open("http://www.example.com/page2.php");` in success callback. I will edit above code so look at it.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works well when I have added the following to prevent the default form sending :

$('form').submit(function(ev) {
 ev.preventDefault();
        ...
});

Comment: Yep, I forgot about it :) Regards ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Jquery.post() with different URLs and the same data. 
More about the usage is here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: I thought about it but how to open another tab ?